# Unable to open ffmpeg mpegts stream on a UDP port on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, video, ffmpeg, streaming

I am trying to display a stream from ffmpeg in a video player.

Originally it was a camera input, but the issue is the same for video files and screen captures.
The code I'm using is a variant of `ffmpeg -i INPUT -f mpegts udp://host:port`

For the purposes of this question, let's say I'm going with:

```bsh
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="CAMERA-NAME" -preset ultrafast -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -b 900k -f mpegts udp://10.1.0.102:1234
```

In macOS and Ubuntu, I can run `ffplay udp://10.1.0.102:1234` or open `udp://10.1.0.102:1234` in mplayer or VLC.

In Windows I'm getting `nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0` from ffplay. The ports are open, the firewall is off, and there is visible packet traffic in Wireshark.

Any ideas what might be the issue?

**[UPDATE]**

I had a stupid idea to try and use `localhost:1234` and it works.
The question still stands: why don't other IPs seem to work?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to indicate which interface to use, as in the below example:-

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="CAMERA-NAME" -preset ultrafast -c:v libx264 -tune zerolatency \
-b 900k -f mpegts "udp://239.0.0.2:1234?pkt_size=1316&localaddr=192.168.1.109"
```